# Click to open div in position clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

so i have a simple question that i don´t know how to resolve.

I have a simple table with some buttons in columns that works as filters and when you click one of this buttons it opens a form.

[image: Form open for filter]

The thing that i need is when you click a button, this form should appear in the coordinates of this button, i tried to get the coordinates of the button and edit the form with this coordinates and it is not working.

I tried to do this for testing

```
document.getElementById('myForm').style.top = "100px;";
```

But is not working.

This is the form

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-container">
        <h1 id="filtername">Filter</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label>Set minimun</label><input id="mininfilter" class="form-control" type="number" value="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <label>Set maximun</label><input id="maxfilter" class="form-control" type="number" value="0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="filtersave" class="btn">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="back_to_normal" class="btn warning"><i class="material-icons">
            autorenew
            </i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
.form-popup {
display: none;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
z-index: 9;
```

}

Thanks guys!

Comment: are you displaying the form on button click?

Comment: Yes, i am, and i am using jquery too

Comment: Try ```position: absolute;``` in the css. Remove the ```bottom: 0;``` and ```right: 0;``` options

Answer (score 1):

So the thing that i did was get the div:

```
var divform = document.getElementById("myForm").style;
```

And obtain the Y and X axes when you press the button

```
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
```

Then when you get this variables i just modify the coordinates of the form

```
divform.top = y + "px";
divform.left = x + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

**https://codepen.io/SachinJerom/pen/zYYOorM**

We can use bootstrap modal for this.check the link given.You can customize the form with styles.`
        
            Filter

```
        <br>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <label>Set minimun</label><input id="mininfilter" class="form-control" type="number" value="0">


            <label>Set maximun</label><input id="maxfilter" class="form-control" type="number" value="0">

        <button type="button" id="filtersave" class="btn">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="back_to_normal" class="btn warning"><i class="material-icons">
                autorenew
            </i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: That is a excelent way to do this but my client doesnt want somethin like that, he want what i said before but i will use this in a future

Comment: (https://codepen.io/SachinJerom/pen/JjjPBjY) try this. check whether it is useful for you.!